# Changing in magento Category layered navigation

Tags: php, magento, navigation, layered

i am using magento 1.9 ce edition for creating an ecommerce site.

I am new to magento and have no experience in that. On my Category page i want to change the layered navigation to plus sign selection not > this anchor selection. i am using ultimo theme, so how can i change the layout of layered navigation.